# Pipeline formatting Issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to format the objects coming from the pipeline as below

```
function Format-Nice
{
        [CmdletBinding()] param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$objects
        )
        process {
            $objects | Format-Table -Property Name, 
            @{Label='Size';expression={[int]($_.Length/1MB) }}
        }
}
```

However, this seems to be breaking each object from the pipeline in a separate table on shell. I intent to write a generic format function which will will provide a custom hashtable expression depending upon the current object type in the pipeline.

Comment: "this seems to be breaking each object from the pipeline in a separate table" I could not reproduce this behavior (in PS 2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SteppablePipeline`, so you does not run new copy of `Format-Table` for each input object:

```
function Format-Nice
{
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][PSObject]$InputObject
    )
    begin {
        $SteppablePipeline={
            Format-Table -Property Name,
            @{Label='Size';expression={[int]($_.Length/1MB) }}
        }.GetSteppablePipeline($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin);
        $SteppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    }
    process {
        if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
            $SteppablePipeline.Process($InputObject)
        } else {
            $SteppablePipeline.Process()
        }
    }
    end {
        $SteppablePipeline.End()
        $SteppablePipeline.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShijuSamuel Sadly, the only thing I can point you to is an official MSDN documentation on [`SteppablePipeline` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline.aspx), but it really lack of examples of usage.

Comment: @ShijuSamuel Another example of steppable pipeline usage can be found  in the `mkdir` function in PowerShell: `Get-Command mkdir|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition`